# Unlock my S4 with a cracked screen?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, broken-screen

I thought I lost my phone so I locked it with "Where's my phone" but it turns out I recovered it with a a useless cracked screen, I know the phone works because it rings and can hear the notifications of messages I get, I want to retrieve the files I have in the internal memory but at the time I plug it in to my computer it says is empty, I'm thinking it says that for security reasons because I remotely locked it. Can someone tell me how to unlock it without a working screen?

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! I've just added the `broken-screen` tag to your question. We've collected quite a few "central details" in [its tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/broken-screen/info), which you might be interested to check.

Answer (score 1):

if your screen would be working temporarily then you need Buy a OTG cable and connect it with **mouse [if pattern as lock] or keyboard [if pin or password]** and you can unlock it without the touchscreen working

Comment: Please add a context to the link you provided. This is necessary as if the link dies the answer will become invalid

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Otherwise, your answer becomes useless in case the link dies (if e.g. the user over at XDA decides to delete the post). For further hints, please see: [How do I write a good answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).